# What song is Castle humming at the end of S01E07?

Tags: castle

I've been catching up on Castle, and the song he is humming on [in this scene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VM482RtZhlk) at the end of the episode ["Home Is Where the Heart Stops" (S01E07)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1345746/) is stuck in my head.  He is trying to stay in the car, he really is, but he is forced into action and an instrumental version plays as he grapples with the bad guy.

I know I have heard this song in later action sequences in the series as well, but the closest I can make from the YouTube comments is that it may be an instrumental version of a Robert Duncan song. I am not sure who that is, but if anyone can give me the title of the song or perhaps a link to the original if it was not created for the show that would be great.

> Penenene nenenene penenene ne ne!

Comment: According to the [Castle Wiki](http://castle.wikia.com/wiki/Last_Call#Trivia) it's an `"action theme" that often plays when Castle gets physical with a criminal`, implying that it is an original composition for the show. - [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Castle/TropesMToP) says: `70's-vintage "action theme song"` - Castle is [playing cop in that scene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0eC6QZijB74), so it makes sense that the tune is related to that.

Comment: Btw, [Robert Duncan](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0242084/) is the composer who does the music for "Castle".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a quick scroll through the comments of the video I managed to find the correct answer, which seems to be [*Eat You Alive* by *Limp Bizkit*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cb24kLd459Y).

Comment: That does appear to be the song, and here I was hoping for an old cop, night rider, or even western type theme song.  Thanks though.

Answer (score -1):

Perfectly appropriate for Castle, he is humming a "classic" 1986 video game theme - NEW COMMANDO ARCADE C64 ELITE 1986/2014 nostalgia COMMODORE 64 CLASSIC RETRO VIDEO GAME

Comment: This has already been answered and downvoted (it has -3 votes). Also, this question has an accepted answer already. Is there a reason you think this is the correct answer and not the song proposed in the accepted answer?

Answer (score -3):

Sounds like commando theme (compare with C64 chiptune version).